# javascript: однострочная проверка значений объекта/массива на заданные значения

Tags: javascript, массивы, объекты

Подскажите, можно ли вот этот код:

```
for (const obj of data) {
    if ((obj[1] == undefined) || (obj[1] == ""))
        return true;
}

return false;
```

или этот:

```
for (const index in data) {
    if ((data[index] == undefined) || (data[index] == ""))
        return true;
}

return false;
```

записать красивым однострочным способом? (может есть какие-то инструменты javascript для этого?)

т.е. смысл - если хотя бы какое-то значение массива пустое или не определено или хотя бы один элемент объекта пустой или не определен, то вернуть true иначе false

Comment: @wololo, это для массива решение, правильно? а для объекта так же будет?

Comment: Я глупость написал. `find()` возвращает найденный элемент, а не `true/false`. Нужен метод `some()`. Впрочем в ответе уже написали.

Comment: Если бы Вам само значение нужно было выводить( и сразу проверять на underfind или null), то можно так arr.forEach((v)=>console.log(v||'нет такого'))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот так

```
const result = Object.values(data).some((item) => item === undefined || item === '');

console.log(result);
```

Или даже так:

```
const result = Object.values(data).some(Boolean);

console.log(result);
```

Но в таком случае `0` будет считаться "пустотой"

Можно ещё так :)

```
const result = Object.values(data).some((item) => item !== 0 && !!item);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: а для Array как бы этот код выглядел бы?

Comment: @Zhihar, `Object.values(data)` — это массив значений из объекта. Т.е. эту штуку заменить на какой-нибудь другой массив, и будет работать. Но тут есть тонкий момент. Цикл `for ... in` перебирает все ключи в объекте + все ключи в цепочке прототипов. А `Object.values(someObj)` возвращает значения, соответствующие только ключам из самого объекта, без прототипов. Иногда это важно.

Comment: @wololo, да, разобрался, вот код: `data.map((obj) => obj[1]).some((item) => item == undefined || item == "")`

Comment: Массив под капотом тот же самый объект, так что в `Object.values` можете спокойно класть как и объект, так и массив.

Comment: @Zhihar тогда уж:
`data.some(([,item]) => item == undefined || item == "")`